# Guzzle Promises Error for Link Checker Module in Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, guzzle

I'm using the Link Checker module (8.x-1.1) on Drupal 9 (9.5.10), installed via Composer.  Guzzle is installed and recently updated during a composer update.

This is from the Guzzle composer.json file in my vendor directory:

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5 || ^8.0",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/promises": "^1.5.3 || ^2.0.1",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.9.1 || ^2.5.1",
        "psr/http-client": "^1.0",
        "symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^2.2 || ^3.0"
    },
```

The PHP error I'm getting is this:

```
Error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle() in Drupal\linkchecker\Plugin\QueueWorker\LinkCheck->processItem() (line 79 of /var/www/html/docroot/modules/contrib/linkchecker/src/Plugin/QueueWorker/LinkCheck.php)

#0 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php(183): Drupal\linkchecker\Plugin\QueueWorker\LinkCheck->processItem()
#1 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cron.php(139): Drupal\Core\Cron->processQueues()
#2 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Cron.php(75): Drupal\Core\Cron->run()
#3 /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/automated_cron/src/EventSubscriber/AutomatedCron.php(65): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run()
#4 [internal function]: Drupal\automated_cron\EventSubscriber\AutomatedCron->onTerminate()
#5 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(142): call_user_func()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(103): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(32): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminate()
#8 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(702): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->terminate()
#9 /var/www/html/docroot/index.php(22): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->terminate()
#10 {main}
```

Link Checker is able to extract all of the links just fine but the links never get checked.  Should I remove Guzzle and re-install it?

I've looked over the code but can't find any glaring issues.

Comment: Looks like someone has posted a patch in the module's issue queue. https://www.drupal.org/project/linkchecker/issues/3387412